Debian 12 and NVME not recognized correctly = disk full and server crash
EDIT 1: managed to restart my server with a power plug pull technique and can now ssh and debug :)
Posting this because at the moment my pi as crashed because I suspect there is somehow no more space on the SD CARD but I was uploading to my external hard drive using FTP in the directory /media/nvme/some/folder/
Getting all this info before the crash and at the moment I can't even ssh anymore. I will try to manually delete some files taking out the SD card and reboot the pi
The 2TB nvme is mounted at /media/nvme and du -sh /media/nvme/ gives 68GB usage only so plenty of space.
I have a homepage service running with config
- resources:
    cpu: true
    memory: true
    disk: 
        - /
        - /nvme # mounted in docker with /media/nvme:/nvme:ro

Homepage disk usage shows 0 space left on BOTH
What could be the cause of this
Here are a bunch of debug commands I did before the crash; please notice that /dev/sda1  which is the nvme does not show up in df but shows in fdisk
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Forty
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5e4c525d

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T 83 Linux

df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3728372         0   3728372   0% /dev
tmpfs             799744      3008    796736   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2 122383952 117122864         0 100% /
tmpfs            3998704         0   3998704   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        16      5104   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1    522232     66670    455562  13% /boot/firmware
tmpfs             799740         0    799740   0% /run/user/1000

lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 119.1G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 118.6G  0 part /

cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=359da976-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=359da976-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  8 15:15 /dev/disk/by-uuid/3b614a3f-4a65-4480-876a-8a998e01ac9b -> ../../mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  8 15:15 /dev/disk/by-uuid/5DF9-E225 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec  8 15:15 /dev/disk/by-uuid/c4aa43d1-a9bc-498c-8549-653c5e929fc2 -> ../../sda1

ls /media/
nvme

sudo du -sh /media/nvme/
68G /media/nvme/



When you say "The 2TB nvme is mounted at /media/nvme", 1) how did you configure it to be mounted there, and 2) how did you check that it is, in fact, mounted there?

@grawity it was a year ago and I do not do this every day but I followed this guide in the link and mounted by UUID. https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux


The 2TB nvme is mounted at /media/nvme

It is not. Your df and lsblk outputs show that it's currently not mounted anywhere at all, therefore /media/nvme currently represents a directory on your SD card, and what got bind-mounted into the Docker container is just the same directory.
It sounds like you manually mounted it once, but forgot to add it to /etc/fstab – which defines what should get mounted on system boot – so the Pi got rebooted sometime later and the NVMe storage never got mounted again, with /media/nvme remaining as an empty directory within your / filesystem.
Mount it manually again (somewhere else, like on /mnt), then move all files from the current "SD card" /media/nvme (regular mv -v should work), then unmount and add an fstab entry so that it will be automatically mounted the next time.

Since the NVMe SSD seems to be connected via USB as an external disk – and since this is a Raspberry Pi without display/keyboard – it might be a good idea to mark the fstab entry as nofail (so that the system will still manage to boot without it being connected), but also make Docker specifically depend on it: either x-systemd.required-by=docker.service as an fstab option, or alternatively run systemctl edit docker followed by adding
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/media/nvme

to the service configuration. That way, Docker will wait for the disk to be connected and won't try to bind an empty /media/nvme into the container, while the nofail option will prevent the rest of the system from getting stuck at the "Emergency mode" prompt.
Alternative approach: Still use the nofail option, but instead of binding /media/nvme into the container specifically, bind the whole /media with the shared propagation mode (e.g. /media:/media:ro,shared if I got the syntax right). That way, even if the NVMe mount is done later – when Docker is already running – it'll become visible inside the containers.

Thank you for the detailed answer and the extra care at the end :) Damn I don't know the fstab got changed and I did not even see it querying it myself; lesson learned :s
